# Kotlin load external class?

Tags: kotlin

I know using `URLClassLoader` it is possible to load external Java files that are not contained in the project src folder.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent method using Kotlin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `URLClassLoader` doesn't load `java` files but `class` files. So you can just use it with `Kotlin`.